# Conver MySQL query with LEFT statment to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Could anybody help to translate below query to Laravel Eloquent syntactics.

```
SELECT LEFT(subject , 10) FROM tbl
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on the top of your Class, Call this

```
use DB;
```

then type this as your query

```
DB::table('tbl')->select('LEFT(subject , 10)')->get();
```